# Magento2 watermark functionality not working

Tags: magento2, watermark

I have installed Fresh Magento2.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 with PHP7.3 version. I have done all the configuration mentioned here https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-image-watermarks.html to add the watermark image.

After added the watermark image configuration I ran below commands
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content-deploy -f en_US en_GB
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento catalog:image:resize

After all doing this , watermark image is not showing on category pages or product detail pages
See below images

[Watermark image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yezL7.png)

Any help will be really appreciatable

Answer (score 0):

- Go to admin side.
- select the content.
- select the design > configuration.
- click on edit action on your store theme name.
- Other setting.
- product image watermarks.

Comment: Can you add the link to the first point? or at least describe more accurately where to start?

Comment: I have already did these settings , but on frontend , no water mark image is shown on product.

Check this .
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yezL7.png

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.3.4 provide to setup water mark for each image type.

Here are image types:

- Base - Display image using mouse hover
- Thumbnail - Display list under base image on product page
- Small - Display on category page

Make sure you have followed all the steps provided by Magento doc
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-image-watermarks.html

I don't think so you need setup upgrade command and static content deploy. You just need to clean cache only.

I have followed same instruction and here is result.

[image: Product Watermark]

Comment: Hi Mehul,
Thanks for your reply. 

But as mentioned in the above query, we are working with Magento2.4 instance not 2.3.4.

And we did follow all the steps and there is no any third party of custom module installed.

Can you please check this on 2.4 and let us know what we are missing? Thanks